# MariaDb Access Denied in JHipster/Microservices/Docker configuration

Tags: docker, mariadb, jhipster

I have created a microservices with JHipster and everything works fine when leaving the datasource settings to their defaults with no root password. The services are started with *docker-compose up -d* and working as expected.

But I want to change the database root password for the different microservices in production, so to do this my understanding was that I will have to:

1. Change docker-compose.yml as follows (relevant parts)

   ```
   microservice1-mariadb:
       image: 'mariadb:10.3.7'
       environment:
           - MYSQL_USER=root
           - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secretPassword
           - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=no
           - MYSQL_DATABASE=microservice1
       command: mysqld --lower_case_table_names=1 --skip-ssl --character_set_server=utf8mb4 --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
   ```
2. Change application-prod.yml of the different services as follows (relevant parts)

   ```
   spring:
   ...
       datasource:
           type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
           url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/microservice1?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
           username: root
           password: secretPassword
   ```

To manually test the connectivity to the database I connect to the microservice1 container and connect with

```
mysql -u root -h microservice1-mariadb -p
```

and provide the secretPassword. This works as expected.

But launching the 'microservice1' container throws the exception:

```
05:38:41.141 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [link/linkfacts/doc/config/LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested e
xception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.19.0.20' (using password: NO)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1087) ~[spring-context-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) [spring-boot-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
      at link.linkfacts.doc.LinkfactsDocApp.main(LinkfactsDocApp.java:65) [classes/:?]
 Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.19.0.20' (using password: NO)
      at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:390) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
      at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:103) ~[jhipster-framework-2.1.1.jar:?]
      at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:93) ~[jhipster-framework-2.1.1.jar:?]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      ... 16 more
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.19.0.20' (using password: NO)
      at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:173) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.6.jar:?]
      at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:110) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.6.jar:?]
      at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1113) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.6.jar:?]
      at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:503) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.6.jar:?]
      at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:155) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.6.jar:?]
      at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:86) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.6.jar:?]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke(<generated>) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$38f29b06.getConnection(<generated>) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:385) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
      at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:103) ~[jhipster-framework-2.1.1.jar:?]
      at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:93) ~[jhipster-framework-2.1.1.jar:?]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      ... 16 more
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.19.0.20' (using password: NO)
      at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.authentication(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:856) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.6.jar:?]
      at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.handleConnectionPhases(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:777) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.6.jar:?]
      at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:451) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.6.jar:?]
      at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1109) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.6.jar:?]
      at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:503) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.6.jar:?]
      at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:155) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.6.jar:?]
      at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:86) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.6.jar:?]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke(<generated>) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$38f29b06.getConnection(<generated>) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
      at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:385) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
      at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:103) ~[jhipster-framework-2.1.1.jar:?]
      at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:93) ~[jhipster-framework-2.1.1.jar:?]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
      ... 16 more
```

I have difficulties understanding which part I am missing?

Comment: Based on some quick testing, the root password is only set on the initial container creation, have you tried deleting and recreating the database container?  This also won't work if you are using Docker volumes (it will load the old config).  Another option is to manually set it though SQL queries.

Comment: It says using password NO so it's a client problem

Answer (score 0):

Indeed problem related to my lack of knowledge regarding docker, and when docker updates images, containers and volumes. All is working as expected after recreating the database container.